# How to target platforms with launch.json

Tags: windows, macos, visual-studio-code, .net-core, launch

The [omnisharp ReadMe](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md) says this:

> **Operating System Specific Configurations**
>
> If there specific commands
>   that need to be changed per operating system, you can use the fields:
>   'windows', 'osx', or 'linux'. You can replace any of the fields
>   mentioned above for the specific operating system.

This is my `launch.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/TestConsole/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/TestConsole.dll",
            "args": [
                "c:\\git\\core\\XunitTestLib\\Steps\\",
                // "~/../../XunitTestLib/Steps"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/TestConsole",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        },
    ]
}
```

When debugging I want to builds on Windows to start with the `"args"` entry which is uncommented, but on mac os I want it to start with the line which is commented out.

I am assuming that I would duplicate the configuration, once for Windows and mac, each, but this statement is confusing:

> You can replace any of the fields mentioned above for the specific operating system.

It appears to be saying that I can replace `"args"` with `"osx"` but that obviously does not work.

How do I create a configuration for a target platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that targeting multiple platforms is a lot easier than I expected and is [explained here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_operating-system-specific-properties) with regards to the `tasks.json` file (but works just the same for `launch.json`).

My launch.json file adjusted for `osx` and `windows` would look like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/TestConsole/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/TestConsole.dll",
            "windows": {
                "args": [
                    "c:\\git\\core\\XunitTestLib\\Steps\\"
                ]
            },
            "osx": {
                "args": [
                    "~/../../XunitTestLib/Steps"
                ]
            },
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/TestConsole",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want some configs to show on windows and others on linux.
I tried this... It works ok on linux - it only shows the linux config, but on windows it doesn't show the windows configs! It says the only configured task is the Linux one!!
Any idea how to fix this?
launch.json:

```
// launch.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "windows": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "C/C++ MSVC: (.exe in /cl/)",
                "type": "cppvsdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${fileDirname}\\cl\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "args": [],
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
                "environment": [],
                "console": "integratedTerminal",
                "preLaunchTask": "C/C++ MSVC: build to cl"
            },
            {
                "name": "C/C++ GCC: (.exe in /gcc/)",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${fileDirname}/gcc/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "args": [],
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
                "environment": [],
                "externalConsole": false,
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
                "setupCommands": [
                    {
                        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                        "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    }
                ],
                "preLaunchTask": "C/C++ gcc: build to gcc"
            }
        ],
    },
    "linux": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "C/C++ Pi: (run from /pi/)",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${fileDirname}/pi/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "args": [],
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
                "environment": [],
                "externalConsole": false,
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
                "setupCommands": [
                    {
                        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                        "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    }
                ],
                "preLaunchTask": "C/C++ Pi: build to pi"
            }
        ],
    },
}
```